# How to create a time-varying date interval variable bounded by a single start and end date

Tags: r, date, intervals

I have a longitudinal data set in which each person has a time-fixed 'start' and 'end' date of observation. It looks like this, for example:

```r
# Populate data frame 
person <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
row <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
start <- c('2011-01-01', '2011-01-01', '2011-01-01', '2011-01-01', '2011-01-01')
end <- c('2015-12-31', '2015-12-31', '2015-12-31', '2015-12-31', '2015-12-31')

# Bind columns together into a data frame
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(person, row, start, end))

# start and end are date variables
df$start <- as.Date(df$start)
df$end <- as.Date(df$end)
df
#>   person row      start        end
#> 1      1   1 2011-01-01 2015-12-31
#> 2      1   2 2011-01-01 2015-12-31
#> 3      1   3 2011-01-01 2015-12-31
#> 4      1   4 2011-01-01 2015-12-31
#> 5      1   5 2011-01-01 2015-12-31
```

I want to create a time-varying interval that calculates 6-month intervals that span the duration of those start-end bounds. **Question:** How can you create this time-varying interval as a set of variables? I'm looking for a solution that doesn't use data.table. It would look like this:

```r
# Populate data frame 
person <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
row <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
start <- c('2011-01-01', '2011-01-01', '2011-01-01', '2011-01-01', '2011-01-01')
end <- c('2014-12-31', '2014-12-31', '2014-12-31', '2014-12-31', '2014-12-31')
IntervalStart <- c('2011-01-01', '2011-07-02', '2012-07-03', '2013-07-04', '2014-07-05')
IntervalEnd <- c('2011-07-01', '2012-01-02', '2013-01-03', '2014-01-04', '2015-01-05')

# Bind columns together into a data frame
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(person, row, start, end, IntervalStart, IntervalEnd))

# format date variables
df$start <- as.Date(df$start)
df$end <- as.Date(df$end)
df$IntervalStart <- as.Date(df$IntervalStart)
df$IntervalEnd <- as.Date(df$IntervalEnd)

df
#>   person row      start        end IntervalStart IntervalEnd
#> 1      1   1 2011-01-01 2014-12-31    2011-01-01  2011-07-01
#> 2      1   2 2011-01-01 2014-12-31    2011-07-02  2012-01-02
#> 3      1   3 2011-01-01 2014-12-31    2012-07-03  2013-01-03
#> 4      1   4 2011-01-01 2014-12-31    2013-07-04  2014-01-04
#> 5      1   5 2011-01-01 2014-12-31    2014-07-05  2015-01-05
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a nested list of start dates at six month intervals
2. Unnest the list so that each start date has its own row
3. Create the interval end date which is the day before the following start date; if the date in question is the last in its sequence, take the end date to be the overall end date

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  mutate(IntervalStart = map2(start, end, seq, by = '6 months')) %>%
  unnest(IntervalStart) %>% 
  group_by(row) %>%
  mutate(IntervalEnd = case_when(is.na(lead(IntervalStart)) ~ end,
                                 TRUE ~ lead(IntervalStart) - 1))
#> # A tibble: 50 x 6
#> # Groups:   row [5]
#>    person row   start      end        IntervalStart IntervalEnd
#>    <fct>  <fct> <date>     <date>     <date>        <date>     
#>  1 1      1     2011-01-01 2015-12-31 2011-01-01    2011-06-30 
#>  2 1      1     2011-01-01 2015-12-31 2011-07-01    2011-12-31 
#>  3 1      1     2011-01-01 2015-12-31 2012-01-01    2012-06-30 
#>  4 1      1     2011-01-01 2015-12-31 2012-07-01    2012-12-31 
#>  5 1      1     2011-01-01 2015-12-31 2013-01-01    2013-06-30 
#>  6 1      1     2011-01-01 2015-12-31 2013-07-01    2013-12-31 
#>  7 1      1     2011-01-01 2015-12-31 2014-01-01    2014-06-30 
#>  8 1      1     2011-01-01 2015-12-31 2014-07-01    2014-12-31 
#>  9 1      1     2011-01-01 2015-12-31 2015-01-01    2015-06-30 
#> 10 1      1     2011-01-01 2015-12-31 2015-07-01    2015-12-31 
#> # ... with 40 more rows
```

Comment: Austin, thanks! Is there also an alternative way to modify it so that in #3, if the date in question is the last in its sequence, the IntervalEnd is still the full 6 months afterward? (Thinking ahead, that may be useful.)

Comment: The current code appears to achieve that so long as 6 months cleanly divides into your total interval as it does here. If the interval is not divisible by 6 months and you would like to extend the last `IntervalEnd` beyond the `end` date so that the interval covers a full 6 months, you can replace `end` in `case_when` with `start + lubridate::dmonths(6)`

Comment: Amazing. Thank you! (yes, the real data are not as simple as the toy data set here)

Comment: To clarify for anyone following this thread, using your thinking, I think this is what we need to extend the last IntervalEnd beyond the end date if we want/need the interval to cover a full 6 months: `df %>% 
  mutate(IntervalStart = map2(start, end, seq, by = '6 months')) %>%
  unnest(IntervalStart) %>% 
  group_by(row) %>%
  mutate(IntervalEnd = case_when((is.na(lead(IntervalStart))) ~ (IntervalStart %m+% months(6)),
                                 TRUE ~ lead(IntervalStart) - 1)) %>%
  ungroup()`